# Image Processing with radon transform

Tags: matlab

I have divided an image into 30 blocks and I want to apply radon transform on each block but I do not know how to do that. I know the radon function in matlab but it is for whole image not for each block.

How may I use the radon function for image blocks?

Comment: This question seems to broad as it is written now. Add where you are stuck with the code and how you are trying it.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the image split into blocks, just call radon() for each block.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `blockproc`, if you have image toolbox.